# tikz/foreach - strange behavior in combination with variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I have made a command `\tl{x}` to "turn left x degrees". Because this is arc and coordinate juggling I have written some test code. Attached is the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{calculator}

\makeatletter
\def\extractcoord#1#2#3{
  \path let \p1=(#3) in \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro#1{\x{1}/\pgf@xx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro#2{\y{1}/\pgf@yy}
    \xdef#1{#1} \xdef#2{#2}
  };
}

\newcommand{\tl}[1]{
  \draw[fill] (\oXPos, \oYPos) coordinate (P) circle (0.5mm) node[right] {P};  
  \ADD{\oDir}{#1}{\oDirNew}
  \draw (\oXPos,\oYPos) arc (\oDir:\oDirNew:\oRad) coordinate (Z);
  \draw (Z) circle (1mm) node[left] {Z};
  \COPY{\oDirNew}{\oDir}
  \extractcoord\oXPos\oYPos{Z}
}

\begin{document}

\def\oRad{20}
\def\oDir{0}
\def\oXPos{0}
\def\oYPos{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
\foreach \x in {1,2} {
  \tl{90}
} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\def\oRad{20}
\def\oDir{0}
\def\oXPos{0}
\def\oYPos{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
  \tl{90}
  \tl{90}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
}
```

You see the tl-command and the test code: foreach-call and manual-double-call.

Surprisingly the foreach is different from the double manual call.  Maybe it has something to do with the way I handle the variables and maybe with the calculator package.

The foreach produces the upper graphic, the manual call below. The lower graphic would be the expected behavior.

[image]

Can you explain this? Obviously there is something wrong with my tl-code.

Comment: I think you want `\xdef\oDir{\oDirNew}` instead of `\COPY{\oDirNew}{\oDir}` to make the new direction global, i.e. known in the next step. However, I would like to draw your attention to `/tikz/turn` which is described on p. 144 of pgfmanual v3.1.4.

Comment: boy, I Should read the manual more often. Thanks, I'm ashamed :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is going on here? `\foreach` loops start a group. Your change of `\oDir` is only local. So in the next step still the old value of `\oDir` is used. What can you do about it?

1. A blunt way of rectifying this is to make the redefinition global by using `\xdef\oDir{\oDirNew}` instead of `\COPY{\oDirNew}{\oDir}`. However, the price you pay is that `\oDir` is global.
2. Another way, which does not make the `\oDir` global, is to use the `remember` key of `\foreach` loops.

I am illustrating the second way since it is less known.

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{calculator}

\makeatletter
\def\extractcoord#1#2#3{
  \path let \p1=(#3) in \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro#1{\x{1}/\pgf@xx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro#2{\y{1}/\pgf@yy}
    \xdef#1{#1} \xdef#2{#2}
  };
}

\newcommand{\tl}[1]{
  \draw[fill] (\oXPos, \oYPos) coordinate (P) circle (0.5mm) node[right] {P};  
  \ADD{\oDir}{#1}{\oDirNew}
  \draw (\oXPos,\oYPos) arc (\oDir:\oDirNew:\oRad) coordinate (Z);
  \draw (Z) circle (1mm) node[left] {Z};
  \COPY{\oDirNew}{\oDir}
  \extractcoord\oXPos\oYPos{Z}
}

\begin{document}

\def\oRad{20}
\def\oDir{0}
\def\oXPos{0}
\def\oYPos{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
\foreach \x [remember=\oDir as \oDir] in {1,2} {
  \tl{90}
} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\def\oRad{20}
\def\oDir{0}
\def\oXPos{0}
\def\oYPos{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
  \tl{90}
  \tl{90}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me also mention that Ti*k*Z has the `turn` key, which you could use here. It is described on p. 144 of the pgfmanual v3.1.4.